# Variable mass, jet airplane thrust

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, momentum, propulsion

Currently struggling with a momentum problem. I have searched other online answers to similar questions, and the solutions contradict the book answer.

## Problem:

A jet airplane travelling $200\ m/s$ takes air into its engines at a rate of $50\ kg/s$. This air is mixed with $2\ kg$ of fuel (per second), burned, and ejected from the rear of the engine at a speed relative to the airplane of $400\ m/s$. How much thrust does the engine provide?

## My Solution:

Let the jet airplane have a mass $M$, just to help with the set up. The fuel, relative to whatever frame the jet has a speed of $200\ m/s$ relative to, has speed $-200\ m/s$.

1. $p_1 = 200M$
2. $p_2 = (M + dM)(200) - dM(-200)$ (Letting $dM$ be a negative quantity)
3. $dp = p_2 - p_1 = (400)dM$
4. $\frac{dp}{dt}= F_E = 400(\frac{dM}{dt}) = 400(-52) =$ **-20800 N.**

The answer in the book is contrarily $10800\ N$. So mine is $10000\ N$ higher. Could anyone resolve this for me, whether I am correct, or the book? If the book is correct, what does my answer actually represent?
Thanks !

Comment: Start again, working in a frame fixed to the plane, and begin by writing down the initial and final velocities of (1) the air and (2) the fuel. In a frame fixed to the plane, the momentum of the plane is zero, so its mass never appears in the equations.

Comment: Fuel has 0 initial velocity, and final velocity 400 m/s relative to the plane, so the force from that is 400 * 2 = 800 N. Air has initial velocity 200 m/s and final velocity 400, so the force from that would be 400*50 - 200*50 = 10000. So then adding the two resultant forces on the air and on the fuel, gets 10800 N. So in this sort of question, it would be better to consider the two separate fluids (air and fuel) and their changes in momentum per unit time and sum to get the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is 10 kN higher because you did not take into account the change of momentum of the airplane picking the air up. Picking up air that's stopped and getting it moving at the aircraft's speed means slowing down the plane down too. It seems you think the aircraft expells 52kg out every second, gaining no mass, like a  rocket would. However, it doesn't. It picks up 50kg of air at some speed, and dumps 52kg of air and fuel mixture out the back at a higher speed. The aircraft loses 2 kg/s, not 52 kg/s.